# Linking files downloaded in a loop, to an identifier in a text list with a bash loop

Tags: bash, ncbi

I have a bash loop which is using a python program to loop over each identifier in a list (text file), to download genomes (files), I'm wondering whether there is a way I can link each file download to the id in the list, as the downloaded files have names which make it more difficult to use later on.

The loop in bash:

```
for i in $(more 'idpandas.txt'); do echo $i; ncbi-genome-download --format protein-fasta --species-taxid $i archaea,bacteria; done;
```

Is there anyway this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure there should be a way. But we need more information: which are the names of the files you are downloading?

```
for i in $(<idpandas.txt)
do
    echo $i
    ncbi-genome-download --format protein-fasta --species-taxid $i archaea,bacteria
    ln -s $DOWNLOAD_NAME $i
done
```

BTW, don't use "more" in the loop list of elements, it is a pager, it will give you problems in this scenario.
Doing the link is as easy as the "ln" line. I bet your problem is knowing which is the filename that is being generated. But that is something we don't even know, either.

Using a dirty way as suggested in one of my comments, you can store the needed files under a folder with your ID. I don't know how your download script works, but I think the following code should do the trick:

```
for i in $(<idpandas.txt)
do
    echo $i
    mkdir $i
    cd  $i
    ncbi-genome-download --format protein-fasta --species-taxid $i archaea,bacteria
    cd ..
done
```

This should give you a bunch of folders named like the IDs in the idpandas.txt file, and inside every folder, the downloaded files by your tool.

Comment: Thanks! The filenames are the genbank/refseq accession numbers, so they look like this: 

`GCF_000337855.1_ASM33785v1_protein.faa.gz`

Whereas my list are the taxaIDs, so they look like this:
`60847`

Comment: Good. And how do you go from 60847 to GCF_000337855.1_ASM33785v1_protein.faa.gz? For a full answer, I need to know how I can generate the filename (GCF_000337855.1_ASM33785v1_protein.faa.gz) given the ID (60847).

The end result you are looking for is a link called 60847 pointing to the file GCF_000337855.1_ASM33785v1_protein.faa.gz, right?

Comment: Yes, the problem is I'm using a python program called ncbi-genome-download: (https://github.com/kblin/ncbi-genome-download), and I really don't have the expertise to edit the source code manually. It will use the NCBI enterez system but I feel that might be getting out of the scope of the original question.

Comment: In fact, I believe your main question is precisely this. Not how to link the files, but how to know which will be the name of the file that you are downloading. This will involve some work on your side to find where this relation can be found. I can help in extracting this information from the web if you need help, but you have to find the web page, accessible using the ID, where the relation is stated.

Comment: Another thing you can do, but it is really dirty, is to download the file in an empty folder and link your ID to whatever has been downloaded. Or slightly cleaner, create a folder with the ID and perform the download there, so you know that all the files inside that folder belongs to that ID. To access those files you just have to go to the folder named like the ID you are interested in and glob whatever is inside.

Comment: I like the sound of this dirty method, although I have over 10,000 different IDs, so would it be possible to automate this process in bash? If so that would be a solution!